WooCommerce check if in single product page and in the main product query
For a Woo e-shop I need to display the price when in the single product page in a particular way. When in any carousel with product cards, like in the home page where you can add various products strips, or even in the single product page for the related products carousels, I need to display the price in another way.
So I thought that the check  if ( is_product() && is_main_query() ) { // one way } else { //another way } would work for my case, but unfortunately it doesn't, as indeed it works for the main product in a single product page, but it also shows the price in that particular way for the related products and up-sells carousels also (which it shouldn't). How can I exclude those? I'm hooking into a 3rd party plugin's hook that doesn't pass any params like the product id, etc...
Any help please?

get_queried_object should give you an idea what "main" item of content you are dealing with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79157577/woocommerce-check-if-in-single-product-page-and-in-the-main-product-query

Please update your question to include more lines of the code, so we can understand the context within which it is running.

The logic needs a slight adjustment: currently, the check is for the main query is a product, but what is needed is if the query is for a product, and if so, check if it's the main query. Something like this (untested):
if ( is_product() ) {
    if ( is_main_query() ) {
        // single way
    } else {
        // card way
    }
}

There are ways to make it prettier, but that's the necessary logic adjustment.

This isn't correct either! What I want is the "single way" when in single product page (is_product) and I'm displaying the price of the current product, and the "card way" when even in single product but showing the prices of any other related or up-sell products in carousels shown behind the primary product, and in any other case (in the loops, in the home page, etc)...
